# Is there a way to monitor memory consumption in Azure Functions with VS Code and Python?

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm testing an Azure Function Time Trigger in Python locally and was wondering if there is any way to estimate the memory size and executions within VS Code so I can get can put this info into the Azure Functions Pricing Calculator.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there way to get it in VS Code, however you can use the AppInsights to send the metrics from local machine and then use the metrics to calculate the executions and memory

You can use the Monitor -> Metrics view in the Azure Portal:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I haven't published the app yet so I can't see it in App Insights yet, but this will definitely be helpful in the future.

Comment: you dont need to publish the app, you can just send metrics to appinsights from local machine

Comment: Hmm I don't see how to do this. I'm only seeing an option to "Deploy to Function App" or to create a new Function within VS Code.